# Open source .net pop3 client that supports SOCKS proxy

Tags: c#, .net

Is anybody aware of any open source .NET pop3 clients that support a socks proxy?

Many thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: On one hand I can see what you mean, but you have to admit that SO and the large number of incredibly knowledgeable people who hang out here is a fantastic resource for questions like this. I've sinned myself a couple of times and gotten really good advice. Anyway, where do you recommend one goes with a question like this?

Comment: @RenniePet I have no Idea where to ask such question. If you have some, please do let me know. I used to close vote these kind of questions, but nevertheless honestly I'll point to some tools/books/libraries if I know one. In this question, I don't know. Otherwise I'd have redirected OP by linking some library in comments.

Comment: I'm not sure how best to rephrase this, but the poster below who answered had a brilliant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [OpenPop](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) or most of the other available POP3 clients) using it's constructor which takes a stream and not a socket, and take any existing SOCKS library and create a [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) on top of the socket it created.